# Windows 8.1 Explorer.exe crash or other issue. when windows start explorer.exe restart several times

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, crash

I have an issue with my windows 8.1 32 Operating system . on starting of windows taskbar and explorer restart again and again. when i kill explorer.exe then it stops and blank screen appear. I think explorer.exe crashed or any other issue. is there any solution except windows installation again?

Comment: Have you checked the system error logs and made sure you have correct drivers installed?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue,

1. Open command prompt with Administrative privilege and goto location  C:\Windows\System32
2. Rename the file "ODBCCP32.CPL" using the command : **ren ODBCCP32.CPL  ODBCCP32.old**

Then Log out and then log back in.  Check the results.

Comment: "please navigate to C:\Windows\System32 folder" how can the OP do this if explorer has crashed?

Comment: This answers the question, but I've downvoted it as the OP specifically said that they are unable to access via Windows Explorer. If you edit your answer to give details on how to do this via `cmd.exe`, I will remove the downvote and upvote instead.

Comment: @cybermonkey, i have updated the answer to run in the cmd.exe.

Comment: yes we can do this by cmd .. Thanks but problem remain as before  :(

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and found that my problem was caused by the Microsoft reporting system crashing. If your problem is like mine, you can disable "problem Reporting".

you can find this option by search "report" on "Control Panel" and:

1. Choose "Choose how to report problems"
2. Select "Never check for Solutions"
3. Click on "OK"

Comment: I know, And I say that I had a problem like he/she, and solved by disable reporting...